# Expo gets stuck during install with npm but installs with yarn and doesn't work

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, expo

When I try installing expo using `npm install -g expo-cli`, it gets stuck for hours here - [expo-cli error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHgy6.png)

> npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@17.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
> [..................] \ fetchMetadata: WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@17.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/

But when I use yarn to install expo, it says expo is installed successfully. But it doesn't work when I type `expo --version` or just `expo` in cmd.

I've tried changing the environment path
I've uninstalled and reinstalled node
I've tried `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 6):

> npm install --global expo-cli --force

That's what did it for me.
Same errors at the beginning of the installation attempt, but afterwards it ignored the issues and installed it anyways.
And it works just fine. Though, usually you should be careful with " --force".

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Windows 10, to be able to install the latest version. I had to install the latest version of Python (3.8.0) and then run `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` as an administrator, then I was able to run again: `npm install expo-cli --global` to install the version 3.8.0 of the expo-cli